# Field search in Ionic, I need to close when the user clicks "Go" or "OK" in the keyboard

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have a search field at the top, which is just a filter, like this:

```
<div class="bar bar-subheader bar-light">
<label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text" size="100" ng-model="q" placeholder="Search" ng-submit="closeKeyboard()" />
</label>
```

With the filter picking up the ***ng-model = "q"*** and filtering on:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="item in ofertass | filter:q | orderBy:someModel | unique: 'cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta'" ng-init="$last ? fireEvent() : null">
```

That works very well, but the client wants that, when he clicks the "Go" or "OK" button of the keyboard, it closes. How can I do this?

This filter is already filtering automatically.

Comment: set/lose focus from the inputbox on submit.

Comment: Hi @Searching How this works?